# Query last n entries od relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

let me give you some context of my problem. I need to query for conversations that are older than two days, have 20+ messages, and where at least one of the last five messages of conversations has to be sent by a real user. Currently, my query looks like this:

```
Conversation::where('created_at', '<', now()->subDays(2))
            ->withCount('messages')
            ->having('messages_count', '>=', 20)
            ->whereHas('lastFiveMessages', function (Builder $query) {
                $query->whereHas('sender', function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->notFictitious();
                });
            })->get();
```

but this query all messages for sender not fictitious not only last five, I believe because this lastFiveMessages relationship is not possible to be like this.

Conversation model:

```
    /**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function messages(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function lastFiveMessages(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class)->latest()->take(5);
    }
```

Message model:

```
    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function sender(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class, 'sender_profile_id');
    }
```

Profile model:

```
    /**
     * Scope a query to only include non-fictitious profiles.
     *
     * @param  Builder  $query
     * @return Builder
     */
    public function scopeNotFictitious(Builder $query): Builder
    {
        return $query->whereNotNull('user_id');
    }
```

Does anybody have some idea how I can tackle this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think because you are getting a Conversation, the whereHas in your query will not limit the future relationships of the Conversation. It will just get you all Conversations that match the query. Conservation->messages() will always contain all the messages..

Comment: You could try using the lastfivemessages as a scope rather than an attribute in this context.